# find a closed formula given by the recurrence, is it possible?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Consider the following recursively defined sequences

1. $$f(n+2)=\frac{4f(n+1)^3+2f(n+1)-f(n)}{4f(n+1)f(n)+1},$$ $f(0)=0$, $f(1)=a$, where  $a$ is real.
2. $2f(n+1)=1+{f(n)}^2$

The first is connected to the parabolic mirror.

I tried to find closed formulas for both sequences $f(n)$ using trigonometric substitutions, hyperbolic substitutions etc., but I failed.
Please help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i'm korean. i'm not good to speaking english. my questions are simple. if exist their closed form, i want to know that. i tried to find a closed formula problem 1&2 during 2 weeks, i failed. i'm not a mathematician. but math makes me crazy. i want to closed form f(n).

Comment: `Mathematica` and `Maple` also failed.

Comment: thanks very much. i will find it.